# Getting an error on my Html Simulator program?

Tags: java, html, stack, queue, simulator

I am getting this error:

```
The method get(int) is undefined for the type Queue<HtmlTag> on line 57
```

Here is the program:

does anyone know what to do because I am in a total lost and this is the last thing I need to do to complete my code

Any help will be appreciated!

```
package HTML;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Queue;

public class HtmlValidator {
    private Queue<HtmlTag> list = new LinkedList<HtmlTag> ();

    public HtmlValidator() {
        Queue<HtmlTag> list = new LinkedList<HtmlTag> ();
    }

    public HtmlValidator(Queue<HtmlTag> tags) {
        Queue<HtmlTag> list = new LinkedList<HtmlTag> (tags);
        if (tags == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(" Invalid ");
        }
    }

    public void addTag(HtmlTag tag) {
        if (tag == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(" Invalid ");
        }
        list.add(tag);
    }

    public Queue<HtmlTag> getTags() {
        return list;
    }

    public void removeAll(String element) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++) {
            list.get(i).getElement().equals(element);
            list.remove(i);
            if (element == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(" Invalid ");
            }
        }
    }

    public void validate() {
        int indent = 0;
        Stack<HtmlTag> t = new Stack<HtmlTag> ();
        HtmlTag currentTag = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            currentTag = list.remove();
            list.add(currentTag);

            if (currentTag.isSelfClosing()) {
                indents(indent);
                System.out.println(currentTag);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: Unexpected tag: " + currentTag);
            }

            if (currentTag.isOpenTag()) {
                t.push(currentTag);
                indents(indent);
                System.out.println(currentTag);
                indent++;
            } else {
                indent--;
                indents(indent);
                System.out.println(currentTag);
                t.pop();
            }
        }

        while (!t.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Error unclosed tag: " + t.pop());
        }
    }

    private void indents(int space) {
        for (int i = 0; i < space; i++) {
            System.out.println("    ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

java.util.Queue interface does not define method get(int). You should use java.util.List if you want a collection with this kind of access.

Observe that your remove code probably won't work at all - you should use Iterator or change your code to use java8 Streams.

Comment: First of all, you have to check for null String in the beginning of your code, so you do not need to iterate on your list. Then, you can use Iterator<HtmlTag> it = list.iterator(); while(it.hasNext()) {if (element.equals(it.next().getElement()) {it.remove();}}. Or, still, change it for java 8 Stream API (leave it to you).

Comment: I just tried your code but it still doesnt remove the tag correctly in the test program

Comment: I do not know your HtmlTag object, so the problem, now, should be the way equality is checked in the "if" statement.